# JS functional filter map vs for-loop, results not the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, functional-programming

If you run the below code snipper, the results of the for-loop and that of the functional filter().map() approach is not the same.

What did I do wrong with the functional approach and what is the functional approach of that for-loop if my method is completely wrong?

```js
var data_obj_arr = [{"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}, {"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}, {"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}]


    function updateChosenOption(category_choice, category) {

        var arr = [];
        for (let i in data_obj_arr) {
            if (data_obj_arr[i][category] === category_choice) {
                arr.push(data_obj_arr[i]["Collection_Name"]);
            }
        }

        console.log(`Array: ${arr}`);

        var results = data_obj_arr.filter((el => el[this.curr_category] === category_choice), {curr_category: category} )
        .map(el => el["Collection_Name"]);

        console.log(`Results: ${results}`);        
    }
        
        updateChosenOption('Built Before 1980','Age')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this.curr_category` in the filter's predicate function with `category`

```
var data_obj_arr = [{"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}, {"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}, {"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}];


function updateChosenOption(category_choice, category) {

    var arr = [];
    for (let i in data_obj_arr) {
        if (data_obj_arr[i][category] === category_choice) {
            arr.push(data_obj_arr[i]["Collection_Name"]);
        }
    }

    console.log(`Array: ${arr}`);

    var results = data_obj_arr.filter((el => el[category] === category_choice))
                              .map(el => el["Collection_Name"]);

    console.log(`Results: ${results}`);        
}

updateChosenOption('Built Before 1980','Age');
```

**Result:**

```
"Array: test,test,test"
"Results: test,test,test"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the value of `this` into the filter callback as the second parameter, you can't use a fat arrow function (`() =>`) because you can't rebind `this` in arrow functions. So if you like this style, you need to use a regular function as the callback:

```js
var data_obj_arr = [{"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}, {"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}, {"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}]


function updateChosenOption(category_choice, category) {

  var arr = [];
  for (let i in data_obj_arr) {
    if (data_obj_arr[i][category] === category_choice) {
      arr.push(data_obj_arr[i]["Collection_Name"]);
    }
  }

  console.log(`Array: ${arr}`);
  //                                 v -- needs to be a regular funtion
  var results = data_obj_arr.filter(function(el) {
      return el[this.curr_category] === category_choice
    }, {curr_category: category}) // < -- to pass in this
    .map(el => el["Collection_Name"]);

  console.log(`Results: ${results}`);
}

updateChosenOption('Built Before 1980', 'Age')
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions use 'lexical scoping' meaning 'this' refers to the current scope and not further. Updating your filter().map() approach (as shown below) will then give you the same results.

```js
var data_obj_arr = [{"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}, {"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}, {"Size": "<1000", "Type": "Detached", "Location": "Northern", "Configuration": "Downflow", "Age": "Built Before 1980", "Collection_Name": "test"}]


    function updateChosenOption(category_choice, category) {

        var arr = [];
        for (let i in data_obj_arr) {
            if (data_obj_arr[i][category] === category_choice) {
                arr.push(data_obj_arr[i]["Collection_Name"]);
            }
        }

        console.log(`Array: ${arr}`);

        var results = data_obj_arr.filter(el => el[category] === category_choice)
        .map(el => el["Collection_Name"]);

        console.log(`Results: ${results}`);        
    }
        
        updateChosenOption('Built Before 1980','Age')
```